# Update + Insert better than Upsert?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

**Explanation:**

Lets say we have a table:

| userid | points |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 456 | 1 |

Both `userid` and `points` is of type `int` or any other numeric data type. And `userid` is my PK. 
Now, in my table I would like to perform an update query, and if the row does not exist I would like to insert the row. If the user already exists I would like to increment the points by 1, otherwise insert the userid and points to be 1 as default.

I am aware I can perform an *upsert* like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(userid, points) VALUES(123, 1)
ON conflict (userid)
DO UPDATE
SET points = table.points + 1 
where table.userid = 123;
```

However, in my case update operation is more frequent than inserting a new row. Lets say there are 5000 queries each day and around 4500 of those rows are `UPDATE` operations on already existing rows. Doing an opposite of upsert would be more beneficial since the conflict will reduce to 500 times instead of 4500. I would like to try to `UPDATE` first and if it returns `UPDATE 0` I would like to perform an `INSERT`.

Is it possible to do the above using `RETURNING` or `FOUND` or something else in a **single query**? Or is the benefit for the above if possible is too insignificant and upsert is the way to go?

A simple representation of what I want to do using python and [asyncpg](https://pypi.org/project/asyncpg/) (2 queries):

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg

async def run():
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(user='user', password='password',
                                 database='database')

    output = await conn.execute("UPDATE table set points = points + 1 where userid = $1", 123)

    if output == "UPDATE 0":
        await conn.execute("INSERT INTO table(userid, points) values($1, $2)", 123, 0)

    await conn.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

**Questions I already have checked:**

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185784/is-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-better-than-inverse) is the most similar to my question for `mysql` but unfortunately does not have an answer.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495587/portable-sql-upsert-insertupdate-solution-needed) kind of works but still uses 2 separate queries and rely upon one query failing/ignoring.
- I also have read
  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762732/how-to-find-out-if-an-upsert-was-an-update-with-postgresql-9-5-upsert),
  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql),
  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964934/update-insert-in-one-query-not-upsert),
  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361768/insert-update-upsert),
  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)
  and
  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)
  but they dont answer my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed code has a race condition: someone could insert a row between the `UPDATE` and the `INSERT`, making both fail. The only safe technique is an endless loop that tries both statements until one of them succeeds.

Since every statement requires a client-server round trip, I doubt that your code will perform better than `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`.

Rather than making an unfounded assumption that `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` is much slower than `UPDATE`, you should benchmark both solutions.

Comment: A while ago I did indeed ran benchmarks (using JMeter) with a lot of concurrent threads than all ran `INSERT ON CONFLICT` statements. When I set it up so that every insert was turned into an update, this performed essentially the same as if I had run only updates in the first place. The same was true, if all inserts were true inserts. And thinking about it, it doesn't really surprise me. In any case Postgres needs to lookup if a row exists and the resulting physical update or insert isn't different.